# Issue while translating ZIP file

Tags: autodesk-forge

Trying to manage XREF. Created a zip file and uploaded to a bucket. then trying to Translate the object

Here the code used for translating the file.

```
`List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>()
                        {
                            new JobPayloadItem
                            (
                                JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Stl, 
                                new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum>()
                                {                                    JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d,JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d},   new JobObjOutputPayloadAdvanced(JobObjOutputPayloadAdvanced.ExportFileStructureEnum.Multiple)                                
)
};
string Base64URN = string.Empty;
Base64URN = Base64Encode(uploadedObj.objectId);
objUrn.urn = Base64URN;
JobPayload job;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(null))
job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(Base64URN,true,DocNo), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));
else
job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(Base64URN, true, uploadedObj.objectKey), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));
DerivativesApi derivative = new DerivativesApi();
derivative.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
dynamic jobPosted = await derivative.TranslateAsync(job);
objUrn.urn = jobPosted.urn;`
```

Exception occured while translating the file.

`at Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.<TranslateAsyncWithHttpInfo>d__10f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.<TranslateAsync>d__105.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
   at Atom.UI.Controllers.Document.BIMViewerController.<CreateBucketTest>d__20.MoveNext() in E:\Codebase\Atom\2018.3.0.0_BIM_360_KALPATHARU -FORGE\Atom.UI\Controllers\Document\BIMViewerController.cs:line 463`

Exception thrown
{"diagnostic":"Failed to trigger translation for this file."}

Answer (score 1):

When translating ZIP archive, specify the model file name in the archive as `RootFilename` (3rd argument of your `JobPayloadInput`) - see details [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/24d9da4a1be19aef38c088a1a854de4e45c1efb5/docs/JobPayloadInput.md)

```
var job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(Base64URN, true, "modelFileName.extensionName"), yourJobPayloadOutput);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. In my code the root file is specified
`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(null))
job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(Base64URN,true,DocNo), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));`

Comment: Then does your root file has the correct extension name that corresponds to its format? Like .rvt for Revit etc. so our service can dispatch it to the correct extractor engine. Also verify that your archive has been uploaded in full with its SHA1 and size values matching your local copy. If all these check pls send the model to us (via weTransfer or dropbox to forge.help@autodesk.com) for further analysis.